# OpenOffice/LibreOffice calc hyperlink

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm using OpenOffice calc (or rather the Libreoffice verion in Ubuntu 11.04). I used the hyperlink function to add links to a column using the function: =hyperlink("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term="&D2,D2)

All appears okay on the spreadsheet, but when I save as html, the links column is saved as plain text and not as hyperlinks to where I want them to go to!

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd ask it [here](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewforum.php?f=7) if I were You.

Answer (score 0):

You could [report a bug](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Report_bugs), but it looks like the underlying problem is that the spreadsheet formulas are removed when saving to html, something as simple as A1*3 is not converted to javascript, and the hyperlink() function isn't converted either. If you insert a link with Insert -> Hyperlink it should work fine.